# Google Analytics Measurement protocol batch request not working properly

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I am trying to send multiple hits in a single request to Google Analytics !
Sometimes it sends one or two hits, sometimes it doesn't send at all !

[image]

I have tried to do the same thing, placing \n after each hit in my request `https://www.google-analytics.com/batch?v=1&t=event&tid=UA-XXXXX-1&cid=555&ec=video&ea=play&el=holiday&ev=300\nv=1&t=event&tid=UA-XXXXXX-1&cid=555&ec=test&ea=test&el=test&ev=test`

But still, sometimes it sends one or two hits, sometimes it doesn't send anything !
Please, help me to deal with this issue !

Comment: What do you meant by send one or two hits? You checking this in network or in GA

Comment: @rajapateriya, I mean when I send multiple events to google analytics using measurement protocol (/batch), in google analytics real time, I sometimes see no event, sometimes one or two of the events

Comment: "I sometimes see no event, sometimes one or two of the events" where are you seeing these events, in Google Analytics portal? If yes then in real time reports or in historical reports?

Comment: @rajapateriya, I see them in real time reports !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using wrong ev values, event value cannot be string it can only be integers. And you are passing ev = test for 2 entries. [Check This](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#eventValue)

For more details on the GA parameters and its value check [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

Answer (score 0):

Try to send with a little delay between the individual hits or add more parameters like location and screen resolution.